# jqGrid filter on multiple columns

Tags: html, jqgrid

In my grid there are 2 columns on which I have to filter.
Columns are server and user.

This is how I am using filter...

```
"groupOp": "AND",
"rules": [{ "field": "user_name", "op": "eq", "data":"User1"},{ "field": "serverns", "op": "eq", "data":"server1"}],
                        "groups":[
                            {
                                "groupOp": "AND",
                                "rules": [{ "field": "user_name", "op": "eq", "data":"user2"},{ "field": "serverns", "op": "eq", "data":"server2"}]
                            }
                        ]
```

So what I am trying to search is that, all the entries where user is User1 associated with server1 and user User2 associated with Server2.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean **AND** (not **OR**) in the statement: "all the entries where user is User1 associated with server1 **and** user User2 associated with Server2"? If the grid contains only 2 columns then it could be no row where the user is User1 and at the same time the user is User2 too. I suppose that you should use something like

```
{
    "groupOp": "OR",
    "rules": [],
    "groups": [
        {
            "groupOp": "AND",
            "rules": [
                { "field": "user_name", "op": "eq", "data": "user2" },
                { "field": "serverns",  "op": "eq", "data": "server2" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "groupOp": "AND",
            "rules": [
                { "field": "user_name", "op": "eq", "data": "user2" },
                { "field": "serverns",  "op": "eq", "data": "server2" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```